# If an odd perfect number exist could be a solitary number?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers, divisor-counting-function

[Perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)  is a number that is half the sum of all of its positive divisors .And [solitary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number#Solitary_numbers) means that  $\frac {\sigma(n)}{n}$ is an irreducible fraction, it's seems to me that all even perfect numbers are irrelevent from the  list of solitary numbers, then i come up with this question: What about odd perfect number if it exist then could be a solitary number ?

Comment: No, that is not what solitary numbers means.

Answer (score 4):

If $n$ is a perfect number then $n| \sigma(n)$ .

A number is solitary when $n$ and $\sigma(n)$ are coprime.

The only way in which a number is perfect and solitary at the same time is if $n| gcd(n, \sigma(n))$ and $gcd(n, \sigma(n))=1$, meaning $n=1$.

But $n=1$ is not perfect.

Comment: A shorter way to show that odd perfect numbers are not solitary is to note that $I(E)=I(O)=2$, where $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ is the *abundancy index* of $x$, $E$ is an even perfect number and $O$ is an odd perfect number.

Comment: BTW, there are solitary numbers $n$ for which $\gcd(n, \sigma(n)) > 1$.